# Is More's 'Utopia' intended to depict an ideal city?

Tags: 16th-century

On the surface 'Utopia' (1516) describes an ideal community : natural law, religion, and reason are its guiding principles. But I come across frequent references to its satirical nature. Does it satirise contemporary abuses in Western Europe, especially I suppose Western Christendom, or is some of the satire directed at the institutions and practices of the Utopians themselves? Or both?

Comment: Don't have time for a proper answer, and its a long time since I read it,but it's largely satire - gold is used to chain slaves, for example - and the clue is in the name, which literally means-‘Nowhere'.

Comment: @TheHonRose. I'd forgotten about the gold chains. A satire on contemporary society which values this largely useless metal ? The utopians take it at its proper value - as only good to make chains and such like with. Thanks for reply. I wonder where the slaves fit into the satire. Is this a point against the utopians, that they have slaves, or is the point that 'we' have slaves too ? Just thinking aloud, not pressing for an answer.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast. Thanks for tidying the question. Much sharper. I am new to the site and new to its style of historical question.

Comment: It is not possible to determine what exactly was in More's mind. Therefore this is a question of opinion. Read those authors who claim satirical nature and see whether they convince you or not.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas I always thought the gold chains was satirising humans for being slaves to money.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_(book)#Interpretation) seems to point to "we don't know" as the answer. Whatever More's intention was, since "utopia" in modern English means "an ideal society", it seems to have been taken as *not* satire at least at some point in history, though.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov Possibly, yes, but it might also relate to More's learned pun - *U*topia = No Place: *Eu*topia = Good Place.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas Glad to be of help, welcome to History.SE, and Merry Christmas. :)

Comment: This might be a better fit for the literature site.

Comment: @Tom Au. Point taken. I wasn't quite clear about the Stack Exchange's categories. Thanks. I suspect the question is a bit too wide as it stands. However long would anything like a full answer be ! Best - GT